Importing CSS class to JavaScript in Docker
I have a project that runs on AWS EC2, but now I'm trying to run it locally. I managed to run container locally, but when I try to connect to localhost:3000 the program throws errors with imports
First of all, I had some warnings with next.config.js when starting container, so decided to fix them first.
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
warn  -     The root value has an unexpected property, webpackDevMiddleware, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, configOrigin, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, target, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
warn  - See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // eslint: {
  //   // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
  //   // your project has ESLint errors.
  //   ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  // },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.externals.push({
      sharp: "commonjs sharp",
      canvas: "commonjs canvas",
      child_process: "empty",
    });

    return config;
  },
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

I've read online that in next.config.js webpackDevMiddleware is not allowed, so I removed it.
Then I was able to run container without warnings.
So I tried to connect to localhost:3000 but error occurred
event - compiled client and server successfully in 810 ms (208 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
error - ./src/pages/index.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/styles/login.module.css'
> 1 | import styles from '@/styles/login.module.css';
  2 | import { useState } from 'react';
  3 | import Image from 'next/image';
  4 | import {rebase_login} from '@/components/rebase_scripts/rebase_plugin'

I checked the @ alias and everything is set correctly. Alias is set to ".src/" and inside container path /src/styles/login.module.css also exists.
There are also files login.module.scss and login.module.css.map but I have completely no clue is this relevant for this problem.
I've read online that this might be Webpack or TypeScript configuration issue, but it didn't work even before I removed that section from next.config.js.
